# How to show the loader center of the mat dialog?

Tags: angular7, angular-material-7

I am not able to show the loader center of the mat dialog.
I am using angular material 7.2 with angular 7 version.
please find my code from below URL.
[Sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugupgr?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Find below css for middle loader for desktop, also responsive for all mobile devices

```
    .mat-dialog-container {
    display: block;
    /* padding: 24px; */
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    max-height: none;
}

    .loading[_ngcontent-ytv-c100] {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 6px solid #ccc;
    border-right-color: #888;
    border-radius: 22px;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 1s infinite linear;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: But i want to open mat dialog top of the window with position absolute and top 6% so in this case it is not working.